# QuickGrid Boolean Checkbox Column?

Tags: blazor, quickgrid

Is there a way to add a Boolean column to a Blazor QuickGrid that can be 'formatted' so that it appears in the grid as a Checkbox?  To be clear, my question is specifically related to Blazor QuickGrid capability.  Fwiw, I know how to handle Boolean values in other types of 'grids'.

For what it's worth, I've looked around quite a bit and haven't found any QuickGrid examples of this. QuickGrid will indeed successfully display the words "True" and "False" to represent Boolean values... and I'm grateful for that.. but I haven't found a way to represent those values as anything but those two strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimal example:

```
<QuickGrid TGridItem="MyClass" Items="@myClasses">
    <TemplateColumn >
        @if(context.BoolVal)
        {
         <input type="checkbox" checked/>
        }
        else
        {
            <input type="checkbox" />
        }
    </TemplateColumn>
</QuickGrid>

@code{
    List<MyClass> myList = [new(),new(){BoolVal = true}];
    IQueryable<MyClass> myClasses => myList.AsQueryable();
    public class MyClass
    {
        public bool BoolVal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You have to take care about the checkboxes being "read-only", style it, etc..

Comment: Excellent!  I spent about half a day trying to find this answer elsewhere and simply could not find it.  In fact, try to find a QuickGrid example anywhere that includes a Boolean column!  If you find it, consider yourself luckier than I am.

Comment: Blazor lets you use a boolean for checked:  `<input type="checkbox" checked="@context.BoolVal"/>` ought to work too, w/o the if/else.